# restrict access to Internet in guest session in 14.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 14.04, lts, guest-session, restricted-access

Ciao!
 I am using ubuntu 14:04 LTS and would like to restrict access to the Internet in guest session at particular times, for example, in use from 10 am to 12 pm and from 5 pm to 7 pm.
For all the day only the network should not be used.
Admin and guest are on the same desktop
thank you

Comment: see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession for restriction on guest session and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1566078 also

Comment: Do you know how you would do it for a regular user? If not, you'd better start to figure that out. Only then the tutorial that @Creator linked to is usful.